# MuPAD: Block Matrices

Tags: matlab, mupad

I'm working with homogeneous coordinates, and like to do some symbolic calculations in muPad.
Lets say my transformation matrix **T** is 4x4, where the upper left is a 3x3 Rotation matrix called **R**, the upper right is a 3x1 vector called **b** and the lower right element is **1**.

So it would be something like:

```
T = [R b; 0 0 0 1]
```

in normal Matlab notation.

Now, i want muPad to work with the symbols **R** and **b**, instead of expanding them and working with the elements.

So, if i define a second transformation **T2** with

```
T2 = [R2 b2;0 0 0 1]
```

the product of T and T2 should be displayed as

```
[R*R2  R*b2+b; 0 0 0 1]
```

i'm new here, so please excuse the bad formatting..(is there a way to include latex?)

Comment: My understanding is that mupad (and the Matlab symbolic toolbox) can only intrinsically handle scalars. So you have to create a symbolic matrix; something like `R = sym('r', [2 2]);`. This will give you a symbolic matrix of `[r1_1, r1_2; r2_1, r2_2]`, where each '`r`' is a symbolic scalar.

Comment: Hi, i do not want mupad (or matlab) to display every element of a matrix operation. Another example may help (with **A** and **B** being matrices): `(A+B)'` should be evaluated to `A' + B'`

Comment: I understand; I don't think it's possible.

Comment: As far as I know, @DylanRichardMuir is correct. You cannot create a symbolic matrix and specify it to have a size, arbitrary or otherwise. I encourage you to [contact The MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs) and create a service request to make this suggestion.

Comment: What a pity...thanks for your thoughts!